# Docker file owners and groups

Tags: docker, ros

I think I have a dilemma. I am trying to create a Dockerfile to reproduce a long and complicated installation process (of ROS) so that my students can get it running with less headache.

I am combining various scripts provided with manual steps that are documented. The manual steps often say to do "sudo" but I am told that doing sudo inside a Dockerfile is to be avoided. So I move those steps to before the USER command in the Dockerfile because I am told that those commands run as root. However as a result the files and directories created are owned by root and I believe subsequent steps are failing.

I have two choices I think: move the commands to after the USER command and include sudo or try to make the install scripts create directories and files of the right ownership. Of course a priori I dont know what files and directories are going to be created.

Here is my Dockerfile (actually one of many I have been experimenting with.) Also if you see any other things that need to be improved or fixed please let me know!

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# create non-root user
ENV USERNAME ros
RUN adduser --ingroup sudo --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell /bin/bash --home /home/$USERNAME $USERNAME
RUN bash -c 'echo $USERNAME:ros | chpasswd'
ENV HOME /home/$USERNAME

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes wget sudo && \
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/robotis_tools/master/install_ros_kinetic.sh && \
chmod 755 ./install_ros_kinetic.sh && \
bash ./install_ros_kinetic.sh

RUN  apt-get install --assume-yes ros-kinetic-joy ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-joy ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-keyboard ros-kinetic-laser-proc ros-kinetic-rgbd-launch ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan ros-kinetic-rosserial-arduino ros-kinetic-rosserial-python ros-kinetic-rosserial-server ros-kinetic-rosserial-client ros-kinetic-rosserial-msgs ros-kinetic-amcl ros-kinetic-map-server ros-kinetic-move-base ros-kinetic-urdf ros-kinetic-xacro ros-kinetic-compressed-image-transport ros-kinetic-rqt-image-view ros-kinetic-gmapping ros-kinetic-navigation ros-kinetic-interactive-markers

USER $USERNAME
WORKDIR /home/$USERNAME

RUN cd /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws/src/ && \
  git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_msgs.git && \
  git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3.git && \
  git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations.git


# add catkin env
RUN echo 'source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash' >> /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc
RUN echo 'source /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash' >> /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc
# RUN . /home/ros/.bashrc && \ 
#      cd /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws && \
#      catkin_make

USER $USERNAME
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

Comment: What is the reason to avoid `sudo` in Dockerfiles?

Comment: Good question. Its been strongly suggested to me here on SO

Comment: And did that recommendation provide argumentation?

Comment: Here is a link for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276426/how-do-i-set-the-password-of-an-account-in-a-dockerfile/54277232#54277232

Comment: Here's another one, look at the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268180/why-does-simple-dockerfile-give-permission-denied/54269736#54269736

Comment: Thanks, got them all and updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Would be interesting for my own information to get why `sudo` should be avoided in containers.

Historically we use `docker` to automate build, test and deploy processes in our team and always tried to write `Dockerfiles` as close as possible to original process.

Lets say if you build in your host some app and launch some commands with `sudo`, some without, we managed to create exactly the same `Dockerfiles`. The positive feedback from this is that you are not obligated to write `readme's` on how to build the code anymore - you just supply `Dockerfile` and whenever someone wants to repeat all steps in non-container environment, he just follows (copy/pastes) commands from the file.

So my proposal is - in Dockerfile install packages first, then switch to user and proceed with all remaining steps, using `sudo` when necessary. You will have all artifacts owned by the user, not `root`.

### UPD

Got the original [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225976/use-sudo-inside-dockerfile-alpine) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269736/10524386) one. So it sounds like you choose the best approach based on your particular case and needs.

Comment: I like your proposal. I will ask for clarification from the person who said not to do sudo.